# Getting data from Background Service in Activity at will

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a following design.

1. Application has registered to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` notification.
2. On receiving the `BOOT_COMPLETED` notification, a new background
   service would be started. This would run indefinitely and
   `START_STICKY`.
3. This Service `onStart(..)` would invoke an
   AlarmManager and schedule it to run periodically (say 15 mins). AlarmManager
   would register a callback using `AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener` which
   would be invoked each time the alarm is triggered. A callback is
   also supplied with reference to a `List<>` object.
4. Each time the alarm is triggered, it would connect to server, fetch some data and store
   with this. This data is stored in the reference of `List<>` passed
   above. So basically, data fetched is stored in Service.
5. During all this time, the `MainActivity` may be killed / closed by the user. However, Service would continue to run as it is a background service.

**Now, my requirement is as under:**

> Whenever a user starts an app (`MainActivity` is invoked) or whenever
> user brings (resumes) an app in foreground, then it is desired that
> the app should check if the service is running (which should be
> running) and then get the data which it has fetched so far, in the
> `MainActivity`.
>
> How can the activity receive this data ?
>
> Remember it is not a simple pass data to activity using Broadcast. I
> do not want the Background Service to Broadcast data each time to
> `MainActivity`. This would result in Broadcast beings sent every 15
> mins (by alarm) to activity which may not be alive to receive. I want
> the `MainActivity` should be able to get the data from Service at its
> own will.

Answer (score 0):

I think `AIDL` is what you need. It can help you to get some running states and call some methods from Service.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl?hl=en
https://www.sitepoint.com/aidl-for-sharing-functionality-between-android-apps/